# Is the following expression a tautology?

Tags: logic, quantifiers, predicate-logic

$\forall x\,(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\rightarrow (\exists y\,P(y)\rightarrow\exists z\,Q(z))$

I believe the sentece is a tautoloogy. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Did you mean $\exists y P(y) \to\exists z Q(z)$?  Otherwise, the right-hand side of the implication is always true and the left-hand side of the implication is not always true, which makes this not a tautology.

Comment: No with that typo, it IS a tautology, since if $C$ is a tautology, so is $A \to C$ for any $A$.

Comment: @EggHead You should show us what you have tried, in the future.

Comment: Oops.  Peter is right of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\forall x\,(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\rightarrow (\exists y\,P(y)\rightarrow\exists z\,P(z))$ is trivially a logical truth, since $C = (\exists y\,P(y)\rightarrow\exists z\,P(z))$ is a trivial logical truth, and if $C$ is a logical truth, so is $A \to C$ for any $A$.

You probably meant, however, to ask whether $\forall x\,(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\rightarrow (\exists y\,P(y)\rightarrow\exists z\,Q(z))$ is a logical truth. But yes, this is too. If any $P$ (should there be one) is a $Q$, then if there *is* a $P$ then there *is* a $Q$.

Comment: I've corrected the typo. My reasoning was that if the left side was false then the entire sentence is true. On the other hand, if the left side was true for all x, then the right side is obviously true. Hence the sentence is true.

Answer (score 6):

**Original Post:**

As stated, the right-side (the consequent) of the implication is always true, because $\exists yP(y) \equiv \exists z P(z)$.

In an implication: $P\rightarrow Q$, whenever $Q$ is true, so is $P\rightarrow Q$ true.

Hence, since the right-side of your implication is always true, so is the entire implication. That means it is a tautology.

---

**Updated post**

Likewise, if you intended to write $$\forall x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)) \rightarrow (\exists y P(y) \rightarrow \exists z Q(z))$$ it too is a tautology, but for a different reason than the above. If the antecedent is false, the whole implication is necessarily true. And if the antecedent is true, then the consequent is true, regardless of whether such an $x$ exists, because if there is any $x$ such that $P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)$, then the consequent necessarily follows. (And if no such $x$ exists, well, then the consequent is true because *its* antecedent $P(y)$ is false, which means the implication on the right-hand side is necessarily true.)

Comment: I've corrected the typo and provided my reasoning for why it's a tautology. Thx!

Comment: You're welcome! Note I too updated my answer!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice original and update :-) +1

Answer (score 2):

It's a tautology. The other answers here explain why very well, but just for an extra perspective, let me show you that it's the case with a tableau. You start with the negation of the formula then apply a series of contradiction-hunting rules to get

[image],

which is **closed** (i.e., its branches end in contradictions), implying that the original formula is a tautology.

Comment: [The code for this tableau is available if requested (but it'll take a while).]